# How to use carbon or map function to format created_at?

Tags: laravel

I make Table CRUD in admin control panel, I will change format of date(column created_at)in Controller with map function with collection OR carbon in table Admin in Database,
I need the date like this (jan 2 , 2017)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use toFormattedDateString in carbon:

```
$user->created_at->toFormattedDateString();
```

also you can change format from model

In your model add an accessor method like this:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->format('Ym-d');
}
```